# VMware Workstation USB Arbitration Service Won't Start Automatically

Tags: windows-10, usb, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

On Windows 10, VMware Workstation  "USB Arbitration Service" won't start automatically at login. I have only one user for PC and it logged in automatically without password.

I looked into Windows services after a successful login, the "USB Arbitration Service" says it planned to start automatically in login, but it don't. I started it manually every time after login.

[Service Not Running Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAxlx.jpg)

Than, it started running normally. However, it resetted every login.

[Service Running Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpxS3.jpg)

After that, I power on the VM. If I did not do it, VM can't see the USB devices. I'm using Workstation 15.0.3  How can I fix it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the service "automatic delayed" from services.msc is solved my problem. Now, it starts automatically without any hassle.